# How to assign dynamic key on $match aggregate mongodb?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, aggregation-framework, aggregate

I want to assign key of $match dynamically as per my condition which I have given below:

```
let memberField = filter == "Agent" ? "user" : "admin";  // memberField = "user"
  
db.aggregate(
            [
              {
                $match: {
                  memberField: "12345"
                }
              }
            ]
          )
```

Here I'm not getting empty response.

But if I pass hardcode key to $match like given below:

```
db.aggregate(
        [
          {
            $match: {
              user: "12345"
            }
          }
        ]
      )
```

Here I'm getting respective result.

So how do pass dynamic key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [`Computed property names`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names).

```
db.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      [memberField]: "12345"
    }
  }
])
```

Comment: @harshadkapei No problem. If it solves your problem, please accept the answer by clicking on the tick, gotta get those internet points! :)

Comment: If this question is helpfull for developer community then please accept the question by clicking up arrow.